# Paypal payflow name value pairs for item names and descriptions

Tags: paypal, payflowpro, paypal-nvp

This is from the PayPal payment page:

Your order summary
Descriptions

```
Current purchase$61.00

Item total $61.00
Tax $5.49

Total $66.49 USD
```

The "descriptions" field is empty and the only thing displayed are monetary values, and not any description of the transaction, users name, or anything.

I'm sending transactions through name value pairs.

```
"USER=".$this->user
 . "&VENDOR=".$this->vendor;
 . "&PARTNER=".$this->partner
 . "&PWD=".$this->pwd;
 . "&TRXTYPE=" . $this->trxtype . "&CURRENCY=" . $this->currency
    . "&TENDER=C" //C = Credit Card
    . "&AMT=" . ($data['price'] + $data['shipping'] + $data['tax'])
    . "&ITEMAMT=". $data['price']
    . "&SHIPPINGAMT=". $data['shipping']
    . "&TAXAMT=". $data['tax']
    . "&CUSTOM=". urlencode("RESEARCH POSTER FROM 1: ".$data['desc'])
    . "&DESC=". urlencode("RESEARCH POSTER FROM 2: ".$data['desc'])
    . "&L_DESC0=". urlencode("RESEARCH POSTER FROM 4: ".$data['desc'])
    . "&L_DESC1=". urlencode("RESEARCH POSTER FROM 5: ".$data['desc'])
. "&ITEMNAME=". urlencode("RESEARCH POSTER FROM 6: ".$data['desc'])
. "&NAME=". urlencode("RESEARCH POSTER FROM 7: ".$data['desc'])
. "&L_NAME0=". urlencode("RESEARCH POSTER FROM 3: ".$data['desc'])
. "&LASTNAME=". urlencode($data['lastname'])
. "&FIRSTNAME=". urlencode($data['firstname'])
. "&EMAIL=". $data['email']
. "&VERBOSITY=" . $this->verbosity;
```

The order summary page, unfortunately, is completely devoid of details.  I can not get it to display any descriptions or item names.

What is the name value pair variables that I'm supposed to use?

I've tried, DESC, ITEMNAME, L_NAME0, L_NAME1, NAME, L_DESC0, etc.  But none of them work.

Comment: Okay...
1) CUSTOM shows up on the merchants transactions record but DESC and Line items don't
2) DESC shows up on the customers reciept but CUSTOM and line items don't.
3) *nothing* shows up on the "YOUR ORDER SUMMARY" page.
4) I had my client send an e-mail asking to enable line-item support and paypal wrote back saying they didn't understand what I was asking.

Comment: The [docs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#sending-a-simple-transaction-to-the-server) state to __not__ URL encode the values of NVPs, among many other things to not do... though perhaps things have changed since when this was first asked. Are/where you getting any kind of response or status code from your query?

Comment: Sorry to see they banned you too in MSE, what happened? Send a link if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_guide.pdf) (starting on page 132) shows L_NAMEn, L_DESCn, etc. starting with 0.  It also has a note...

> To enable line-item support, send an email from the Primary email
>   address on  the account to payflow-support@paypal.com

Did you do that?

Comment: Well, no.  Because I don't have access to the primary email of the account holder.  I am the developer hired by the account holder.  I am not the account holder.

And I don't *want* line items.  The purchase is of simply one item.  Is there no way to to list the name or description for a single transaction in whole?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using the `SetExpressCheckout` API. In my case, I was using the API shown at Paypal's [Customizing Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/) page; the one with the longer argument names — `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT` instead of `AMT`, and so on. But even with that, I wasn't getting line items, subtotals, and totals.

In the end, I discovered that adding `VERSION=109.0` to the URL arguments fixed my problem. Without that, PayPal's server appeared to be using Version 54.0, which I guess doesn't support line items and totals.